# C++ help and questions

Tags: c++

I need help making an c++ program with a function that uses int `Disc(int A, int B, int C)` and calculates returns `B*B-4*A*C` and use the function Disc in the program..... i have this so far.

```
void main(){
     cout << Disc(a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: Thats a good start. You're making the function call. Now you need to define the function and also define the variables a,b and c.

Comment: And your question (bearing in mind this is not a code-writing service) is what?

Comment: @codaddict: Hmm... it seems half of that function is already written too. Just need to define the body of that function... hey, I see a function called `main` in there. Perhaps @user267237 could use that as a template? An example for creating the `Disc` function, perhaps?

Comment: We all pretend to *help* the OP learn, but the answer will be posted within 10 minutes.  Just sit tight, *user267237*!

Comment: alright i will try that.

Comment: lol yea i see that sometimes even though thats not helping anyone.

Comment: @STingRaySC, are you a mentalist?

Comment: @STingRaySC, nope, you are a mentalist :)

Answer (score 5):

What does the book you are using say about functions?

Assuming you can't get a book, take a look that [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) on functions (See the edit below)

You already have the function definition. The name, what parameters it takes and what it returns so if you take some time looking at the above tutorial you should be able to put something together (All you need to do is to write the body of the function).

The one thing that may cause you an issue (compiler error) is if you don't put it above the `main` function as either the function definition or the function itself must come before it is used. For simplicity at this point I reccomend you just put the function itself above the `main` function as shown in first example in the tutorial I linked to.

**EDIT** about linked tutorial
It suggests you use `return` with brackets. Example:

```
return (5);
```

Where as it should be used without them. Example:

```
return 5;
```

Comment: Obsolete return syntax and namespaces in the same example?? Anyway, there must be a better tutorial

Comment: @Ernelli Ouch, I just noticed that. Any recommendations would be welcome.

Comment: I noticed that it was the first result on google "C++ tutorial", I tried "good C++ tutorial" it was still first. Anyway, a real good C/C++ tutorial that could be to refered to would be nice. Any suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so you define the function Disc then:

`int Disc(int A, int B, int C)
{
  /* tricky part goes here... */
}`

Comment: Here's a hint: The *tricky part goes here* part is **already in your post**!